# Change radio button check state base on text field value

Tags: javascript, radio-button

Sorry I'm fairly new to javascript and need help. I have this form which inputs a whole number on a text field, and I want to automatically change a radio button's check state base on the value of the text field.

so if the value is more than 20, the "Sometimes" radio button is checked.
If value is more than 40 the "Often" Radio button is checked. but if value is less than 20 the "Never" radio button is checked

Here is my code so far.

HTML

```
    1. DT Result
    <input class="DT-input-container" id="DTResult" name="DTResult" type="text" value=""/><label for="inf_option_1DigestiveTract">1. Digestive Tract</label>
            <input checked="checked" id="inf_option_1DigestiveTract_748" name="inf_option_1DigestiveTract" type="radio" value="748" />
            <label for="inf_option_1DigestiveTract_748">Never</label>
            <input id="inf_option_1DigestiveTract_752"  name="inf_option_1DigestiveTract" type="radio" value="752" />
            <label for="inf_option_1DigestiveTract_752">Sometimes</label>
            <input id="inf_option_1DigestiveTract_750" name="inf_option_1DigestiveTract" type="radio" value="750" />
            <label for="inf_option_1DigestiveTract_750">Often</label>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Javascript

```
$(function() {
var result1 = document.getElementById('inf_custom_1DigestiveTractResult').value
    if ( result1 > 20 ) {
        $("input[id=inf_option_1DigestiveTract_752]").attr('checked', true);
    } else if ( result1 > 40 ) {
        $("input[id=inf_option_1DigestiveTract_750]").attr('checked', true);
    }});
```

Comment: I guess "Sometimes" radio button must be getting checked even if the number is greater than 40. Is this is what's happening? If thats the case then write first condition like this: if (result1 > 20  && result1 <=40)

Comment: @nehal-gala ops, i think that was supposed to be greater than 20 but less than 40. sorry, didn't realize that. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably are looking for is tracking the `onkeyup` event ([jquery](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/))

```
$('DTResult').keyup(function() {
    var len = $(this).val().length;

    if (len < 20) {
        $("#inf_option_1DigestiveTract_748").attr('checked', true);
    else if (len >= 20 && len < 40) {
        $("#inf_option_1DigestiveTract_752").attr('checked', true);
    } else {
        $("#inf_option_1DigestiveTract_750").attr('checked', true);
    }
});
```

edit: requirements changed

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var setDTcheckboxes = function () {
        var len = $(this).val().length;

        if (len < 20) {
            $("#inf_option_1DigestiveTract_748").attr('checked', true);
        else if (len >= 20 && len < 40) {
            $("#inf_option_1DigestiveTract_752").attr('checked', true);
        } else {
            $("#inf_option_1DigestiveTract_750").attr('checked', true);
        }
    }

    $('DTResult').keyup(setDTcheckboxes);
    setDTcheckboxes();
});
```

Comment: sorry, is there another way if the text field's value is added dynamically instead of the user typing it in.

Comment: changed my answer to fit with that - if it changes dynamically, another way, you'll have to either add a listener to that event or create [your own event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/).